# Having issues with git svn clone a non-standard repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

### Background

I am working with a huge SVN repository (full clone is ~20Gb), it has the following top-level strucuture:

```
stuff
stuff/branches
stuff/tags
stuff/trunk
stuff/archive
stuff/build
stuff/machines
stuff/releases
```

First point: I have no clue what stuff is contained in the [archive, machines, build & releases] directories and to be honest - I don't really care - I just know I don't need them stored locally to do development work.

Second point: Other than the silly directories for storing artifacts, on the surface this seems like a standard SVN layout. However, when you dig deeper, it's bizzare as the trunk directory contains multiple projects, for example:

```
stuff/trunk/mars
stuff/trunk/earth
stuff/trunk/venus
stuff/trunk/saturn
stuff/trunk/pluto
...
```

And the branches folder has been organised as described:

```
stuff/branches/<project>-<name of project branch>
```

Where each branch has been branched from one of the projects in:

```
stuff/trunk/<project>
```

### What am I trying to achieve?

I only want to clone stuff from the pluto project (~20Mb). For example  when doing this in SVN, I would issue the following command:

```
svn checkout https://svn.example.com/svn/stuff/trunk/pluto
...
Checked out revision 3505
```

My issue is that I am unable to replicate this using git-svn. I've tried numerous times with different options to "git svn clone" and every time I end up cloning the entire repo (~20Gb) or nothing. Surely it shouldn't be this difficult so I must be doing something wrong.

If I'm able to git-svn clone just the pluto project, when I create a new branch with git-svn I also want it to create me an SVN branch, for example, I want the following commands to be equivalent:

```
svn copy https://svn.example.com/svn/stuff/trunk/pluto \
    https://svn.example.com/svn/stuff/branches/pluto-1234 \
    -m "Making branch pluto-1234 from /stuff/trunk/pluto"

git svn branch -m \
    "Making branch pluto-1234 from /stuff/trunk/pluto" \
    pluto-1234
```

So that a new SVN branch is created at the following location:

```
stuff/branches/pluto-1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git svn clone --trunk stuff/trunk/pluto --branches stuff/branches --include-paths='stuff/branches/pluto-.*'
```

`pluto-.*` is a regular expression to select desired branches. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt---include-pathsltregexgt

Comment: Thanks.... Your hint helped me work out how to solve the problem!

The command I issued was:

git svn init https://svn.example.com/svn/stuff --trunk=trunk/pluto --branches=branches/* --include-paths=branches/pluto-* --prefix=git-svn/ pluto